# GWT-PhoneGap integeration

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, cordova

I am looking for integrating gwt with phonegap , i grabbed one from  [Phonegap Jar available for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/) , but i could not find any resource how to implement phonegap with GWT, i.e i could not find a way how to associate gwt objects like buttons,textarea,events with phone gap. I did look at [Getting started with gwt and phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/GettingStarted) ,but the resources only provide details about available methods with phonegap(events,loctaions,timers etc..). Could anyone please  provide me any example(#hello world#) how to integrate gwt and phonegap or any resource which gives a simple  example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an additionl project "showcase" for using GWT and phonegap at that repository:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/source/checkout?repo=showcase

You can also take a look at [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/). That is a framework for creating mobile applications with GWT. It has a lot of widgets for mobile webkits browser. It works really good with gwt-phonegap.